# Converting a DataMap to a String or String Array

Tags: java, android, string, wear-os

I'm in the process of transferring weather data from an Android phone to a Android Wear wearable via DataMap.

I have managed to get the DataMap on the device but need to find a way how to convert it into either one long string (then split into an array) or a string array.

Any ideas?

Current Code on Phone:

```
DataMap dataMap = new DataMap();
dataMap.putLong("1-#TIME-STAMP:", System.nanoTime());
dataMap.putLong("2-#CONTENT:", 0);
dataMap.putString("time:", currentWeather[0]);
dataMap.putString("summary:", currentWeather[1]);
dataMap.putString("icon:", currentWeather[2]);
dataMap.putString("nearestStormDistance:", currentWeather[3]);
dataMap.putString("nearestStormBEaring:", currentWeather[4]);
dataMap.putString("precipIntensity:", currentWeather[5]);
dataMap.putString("precipPRobability:", currentWeather[6]);
dataMap.putString("temperature:", currentWeather[7]);
dataMap.putString("apparentTemperature:", currentWeather[8]);
dataMap.putString("dewPoint:", currentWeather[9]);
dataMap.putString("humidity:", currentWeather[10]);
dataMap.putString("windSpeed:", currentWeather[11]);
dataMap.putString("windBearing:", currentWeather[12]);
dataMap.putString("visibility:", currentWeather[13]);
dataMap.putString("cloudCover:", currentWeather[14]);
dataMap.putString("pressure:", currentWeather[15]);
dataMap.putString("ozone:", currentWeather[16]);
new SendToDataLayerThread("/data_from_phone", dataMap).start();
```

Current Code on Wearable:

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents)
{
    DataMap dataMap;
    for (DataEvent event : dataEvents)
    {
        Log.v("myTag", "DataMap item: " + DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem()).getDataMap());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you want all the values in an string array. Once you have your datamap object on device, you can do that in following manner:

```
 ArrayList<String> listOfDataItems = new ArrayList<String>();
 for(String key: dataMap.keySet())
 {
    Object value = get(key);
    if(value instanceof Long)
    {
        listOfDataItems.add(String.valueOf(value));
    }
    else if(value instanceof String)
    {
        listOfDataItems.add(value);
    }
 }
 String [] arrayOfDataItems = listOfDataItems.toArray(new String[listOfDataItems.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using Gson ? You could directly write Gson.toJsonString(dataMap).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem with using `DataMap.putStringArray (String key, String[] value)`? Looking at your code, it seems you could use that for your entire `currentWeather` array, if you want it in the same format on the wearable device.

Doumentation: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataMap.html#putStringArray(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])